# How to add margin to first element on axis using pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to add margin to the 0's on the x and y-axis, so that my markers don't stand on the axis' themselves, when I've points (0,y) and (x,0).

How can I add margins to the first elements on the axis?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,compat=1.9}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={\textbf{Temperature dependence of CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O solubility}},
    xlabel={Temperature [\textcelsius]},
    ylabel={Solubility [g per 100 g water]},
    xmin=0, xmax=120,
    ymin=0, ymax=120,
    xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
    ytick={0,20,40,60,80,100,120},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=*,
    mark options={scale=1.50}
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,23.1)(10,27.5)(20,32)(30,37.8)(40,44.6)(60,61.8)(80,83.8)(100,114)
    };

\addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=triangle*,
    mark options={scale=1.50},
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,25.8)(10,29.5)(20,34)(30,39)(40,48)(60,64)(80,86)(100,117)
    };
    \legend{Local, Oraclize}    

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an answer in your code already: `xmin`,`xmax`,`ymin`,`ymax`, which sets the axis limits, so you can change those values to what you find appropriate.

Alternatively you can remove all those settings, in which case `pgfplots` will set the axis limits so that all of the data is shown, and there is some padding around the data. You can also modify how much padding there is, with the `enlargelimits` option. For example if you add `enlargelimits=0.05` to the `axis` options, the padding will be 5% of the data range.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,compat=1.9}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={\textbf{Temperature dependence of CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O solubility}},
    xlabel={Temperature [\textcelsius]},
    ylabel={Solubility [g per 100 g water]},
    xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
    ytick={0,20,40,60,80,100,120},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=*,
    mark options={scale=1.50}
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,23.1)(10,27.5)(20,32)(30,37.8)(40,44.6)(60,61.8)(80,83.8)(100,114)
    };

\addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=triangle*,
    mark options={scale=1.50},
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,25.8)(10,29.5)(20,34)(30,39)(40,48)(60,64)(80,86)(100,117)
    };
    \legend{Local, Oraclize}    

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```